# Comparing elements in a circular array(java)

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, circular-reference

i am trying to formulate a for loop that will take an array, for instance of 5 elements, and will allow me to treat `a[0]` as if it is after `a[4]`, and `a[4]` as if it was before `a[0]`.

I cannot change the array, and it stores a thread in each element, so i would rather make it as simple as possible to not corrupt the contents of the thread(threads are synchornized and using reentrantlock - so the question is only about array).

I want to make this simple for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE; i++)
```

to allow me to treat it as if it was a cyclic array. I thought of using the mudolo operation to achieve that, but that doesn't work either. here's what i tried:

```
for (int i = i+1 % n; i < ARRAYSIZE; i++)
```

but that doesn't work as well. What I am trying to do is basically check if `array[i]` is larger than `array[i+1]` or `array[i-1]`.

would appreciate your assistance.

Comment: a[i%5] --------

Comment: What exactly do you mean by cyclical? Do you want the loop to terminate when `i < ARRAYSIZE` is `false`?

Comment: Are other data structures allowed here? (You tell me.) I wonder if a circular linked list is more appropriate than an array here, anyway.

Comment: thank you for your comment, but the question was about arrays. linked lists next time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the modulo operator on the loop variable `i` by the size of the array:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {

    int [] arr = {1, 5, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 1};
    int ARRAYSIZE = arr.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE; i++) {
        int index = i % ARRAYSIZE;
        int indexUpper = (i + 1) % ARRAYSIZE;
        //access array using index
        if (arr[index] == arr[indexUpper]) {
            System.out.format("Elements %d and %d are equals.\n", index, indexUpper);
        }
    }
}
```

Note how for the upper value you want to cycle through, you need to do `(i + 1) % ARRAYSIZE` to ensure you get the next element.  To get the element *two* places over, add `2` instead, or whatever modifier you choose.

This test shows how elements 7 and 0 are equal because it is cyclical.

**Output:**

> Elements 3 and 4 are equals.
>
> Elements 7 and 0 are equals.

Comment: thank you very much! can i ask more questions about this topic if i encounter them later?

Comment: @proggy It would probably be better to make a new question on it to garner more response if it is completely new, but if it is related feel free to ask me here.

Comment: i've been having a problem with your solution. you've helped me with the upperindex, but regarding the lowerindex there's a problem, at least for me: since int indexLower = (i - 1) % ARRAYSIZE; we get that i-1 equals -1 and that's out of bounds exeception. how can it be solved?

Comment: @proggy If you are making it circular, why are you attempting to go behind it?  It will circle around with `i + 1` and return the same results anyway.

Comment: @proggy For example if you want to compare values to before it and after it, just compare `i + 1` to `i` and `i + 2` and it will be the same.

Comment: thanks, understood it. however i still happen to have big bugs in the program i tried to implement. if i post it as a question, can you please take a look?

Comment: @proggy Sure I am always looking, there are plenty of other people I am sure willing to help if you make it easier to reproduce and easy to understand.